# Is it possible to filter top to show specific processes?

Tags: ubuntu, performance-monitoring, top

I'm run top and I want to always see java/tomcat/redis/mysql/mongo, is that possible?

Answer (score 23):

You could to something like this

```
top -p `pgrep -d ',' "java|tomcat|redis|mysql|mongo"`
```

This gets `pgrep` to produce a comma separated list of pid's that are passed to `top -p`

Comment: Much simpler :)

Comment: I was struggling to figure out how to find the process list for multiple process names till I saw how you did it.

Comment: A note to future viewers - this method may not give you the data you are expecting.  a) this method shows only processes running when top is *started*.  Top's normal behavior is to show processes new since it began.  b) the top manual I read says -p is limited to 20 process ids.  see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075591/top-c-command-in-linux-to-filter-processes-listed-based-on-processname

Comment: After running top -c , hit o and write a filter on a column, e.g. to show rows where COMMAND column contains the string foo, write COMMAND=foo

Answer (score 6):

Not quite what you're looking for, but sometimes a process is run by it's own user, like apache2 is often run by user www-data.

You can use that to limit top's output to only the processes by that user, effectively only showing apache2 processes by using this command:

```
top -u www-data
```

Comment: Great! I was wondering how to list user specific processes

Answer (score 5):

Check **man top** manual page for more details about top utility...

Semms you need -p parameter

> -p : Monitor PIDs as:  **-pN1 -pN2 ...**  or  **-pN1, N2 [,...]**
>
> ```
>         Monitor only processes with specified process  IDs.   This  option
>         can  be given up to 20 times, or you can provide a comma delimited
>         list  with  up  to  20  pids.   Co-mingling  both  approaches   is
>         permitted.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
alias mytop='echo $(sed "s/\([0-9]*\)/-p \1/g;s/^/top /" <(pgrep -d" " "java|redis|mysql|mongo"))'
mytop
```